# Eclipse Scout modal view error

Tags: eclipse-scout

I am working in new Scout Neon and I am starting to get error :

```
Assertion error: Property 'modal' cannot be changed because Form is already showing
```

My forms has properties :

```
@Override
protected int getConfiguredModalityHint() {

   return MODALITY_HINT_MODELESS;
}

@Override
protected int getConfiguredDisplayHint() {

   return DISPLAY_HINT_VIEW;
}

@Override
protected String getConfiguredDisplayViewId() {

  return VIEW_ID_CENTER;
}
```

What I did wrong?

EDIT : Marko

---

I add page in `MyOutline` witch extends from `AbstractOutline`

```
public class MyOutline extends AbstractOutline {

  @Override
  protected String getConfiguredTitle() {

    return TEXTS.get("MyOutline");
  }

  @Override
  protected void execCreateChildPages(final List<IPage<?>> pageList) {

    final MyPage myPage = new MyPage();

    pageList.add(myPage);
    super.execCreateChildPages(pageList);
  }
}
```

`MyPage` is only a wrapper page for form.

```
public class MyPage extends AbstractPageWithNodes {

  @Override
  protected boolean getConfiguredLeaf() {

    return true;
  }

  @Override
  protected boolean getConfiguredTableVisible() {

    return false;
  }

  @Override
  protected String getConfiguredTitle() {

    return TEXTS.get("MyPage");
  }  

  @Override
  protected Class<? extends IForm> getConfiguredDetailForm() {

    return MyForm.class;
  }
}
```

and my form is nothing spacial :

```
@FormData(value = MyFormData.class, sdkCommand = FormData.SdkCommand.CREATE)
```

public class MyForm extends AbstractForm {

```
  /**
   * Method start Form for adding new person.
   */
  public void startNew() {

    this.startInternal(new NewHandler());
  }

  @Override
  protected boolean getConfiguredAskIfNeedSave() {

    return false;
  }

  @Override
  protected int getConfiguredModalityHint() {

    return MODALITY_HINT_MODELESS;
  }

  @Override
  protected int getConfiguredDisplayHint() {

    return DISPLAY_HINT_VIEW;
  }

  @Override
  protected String getConfiguredDisplayViewId() {

    return VIEW_ID_CENTER;
  }

  public MainBox getMainBox() {
 ...
```

But when I want to open this Page (on start application is not opened on this page), (and I do not do anything else before) I get error.

```
 2016-01-22 11:13:56,236 ERROR scout-model-thread-11 'Processing JSON request' o.e.scout.rt.platform.exception.ExceptionHandler -  
 org.eclipse.scout.rt.platform.util.Assertions$AssertionException: Assertion error: Property 'modal' cannot be changed because Form is already showing 
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.platform.util.Assertions.fail(Assertions.java:581) ~[org.eclipse.scout.rt.platform-5.2.0.M4.jar:5.2.0.M4]
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.platform.util.Assertions.assertFalse(Assertions.java:192) ~[org.eclipse.scout.rt.platform-5.2.0.M4.jar:5.2.0.M4]
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.client.ui.form.AbstractForm.setModal(AbstractForm.java:2700) ~[org.eclipse.scout.rt.client-5.2.0.M4.jar:5.2.0.M4]
at org.eclipse.scout.rt.client.ui.desktop.outline.pages.AbstractPage.decorateDetailForm(AbstractPage.java:692) ~[org.eclipse.scout.rt.client-5.2.0.M4.jar:5.2.0.M4]
```

Comment: Is this error coming when you call `setModal(..)` ? Please confirm or add the stacktrace you get with the error. If this is the case, when do you call `setModal(..)` what are you do before this call?

Comment: I don't call setModal(...) directly, but it is called with getConfiguredModality.. So before I don't call ant thing...

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for my problem.

in my constructor in form I have :

```
public PersonsExtensionFieldForm() {
    this.startInternal(new NewHandler());
}
```

witch is ok, when you open form from other form with for example button click.

But when you put form in page as `Detail` form you need to have

```
 public PersonsExtensionFieldForm() {
    this.setHandler(new NewHandler());
 }
```